# Rails Dev Server localhost super slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

I'm developing a rails app and I have a performance issue that it's super annoying. When I'm running the server on my pc (Ubuntu 11.10 - Thin server) it's super slow, every new request can take up to 3-4 minutes. This doesn't happens on the production server, on production everything runs smoothly.

I suspect it may be sphinx that it's not properly configured to work on my localhost, what do you think? You need more info? Gemfile?

Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I think your machine is just slow. You can take a look into actioncontroller::base and see all that it includes to get an idea of what each request is doing. If you want to speed up your requests, try looking into actioncontroller::metal. It's stripped down version of actioncontroller::base, and looks pretty much like rack. that means it doesnt go through a templating engine, or have layouts and helpers, and a whole bunch of other things.

Comment: I've tried other projects in my pc and they run just fine, that's why I think is a particular problem with this one.

Answer (score 0):

3/4 minutes for a request is really too much... Anyway I was able to speed up my development setup using dev-tweaks, a gem that helps serving assets faster: it can't hurt!

https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks

Comment: I'll try it and let you know!